Lock free counter for two atomic ints
I want to implement a lock-free structure, that returns values strictly in an ascending order. I have 2 atomic int's and want to make long from them, so the idea is to firstly increment first memory chunk, and then, once it reaches max value for int, increment the second by one and set first to 0.
I've managed to write this code, but it is not working due to sometime making an ABA-like problem (memory first set to 0 by some thread, while other start to read it and get the wrong value, without incrementing second memory)
    unsigned int second = secondmem -> load(), first = first = firstmem->load();
    while (true) {
        unsigned int nfirst = first + 1, nsecond = second;
        if (first == UINT32_MAX) {
            nfirst = 0;
            nsecond = second + 1;
        }
        if (!secondmem->compare_exchange_strong(second, nsecond)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!firstmem->compare_exchange_strong(first, nfirst)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (secondmem->compare_exchange_strong(second, second)) {
            return convertInts(nsecond, nfirst);
        }
    }

The structure definition
struct MyStruct {
    std::atomic_uint32_t *firstmem, *secondmem;

    MyStruct(std::atomic_uint32_t & mem1, std::atomic_uint32_t & mem2)  {
        firstmem = &mem1;
        secondmem = &mem2;
    }

    unsigned long long get();


Why not just use a std::atomic<int64_t>?

We need to see the struct definition(s) for the pointers firstmem/secondmem. Please edit your question and add these in a code block.

Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics shows how to use a seqlock for this so readers can avoid torn reads.  With a counter that only ever increments by 1, you can use the low half as the sequence number to detect tearing, reading it twice (before/after the high half).  But if multiple increments can be in-flight at once, that complicates things.  Keep in mind many modern platforms have lock-free atomic<uint64_t> support, including many 32-bit ones, but not all.

What consistency requirements do you have for readers?  If those aren't very strict, you should just be able to use fetch_add (with the high-half increment being conditional on carry-out.  carry = a < (a+b) for unsigned). Whatever order ends up happening, the right number of carries into the high half will happen.  If consistency / 64-bit atomicity requirements are strict, this is a non-starter; you can't avoid partial transactions being visible to other readers and writers if you do anything like this without a lock or sequence-number.

I cannot use a std::atomic<int64_t> because I have two 32 bits memory segments that dont necessarily follow each other, so I need to simulate 64 bits atomic counter with two 32 ones.
I understand that I cannot strictly do it, so I was interested, how many values can be recieved without breaking lock free (e. g. you can make a counter for 2^48 values, if you use half of the first 32 bits for synchronizing etc.)

Correction to my earlier comment; low.load() ; high.load() ; low.load() as a way to detect tearing only works if writes to the whole 64-bit value are atomic, like you'd have with a counter from an interrupt handler that could interrupt readers on a uniprocessor machine.  If a writer has to update one half or the other separately, then it's possible for the reader to see either the low half roll back to 0 without a high-half increment, or the high half increment while the low half is still 2^32-1.

A separate sequence number works, e.g. using some bits of one half, but might need locking between writers.  (And might have a lot of retries for readers if there are frequent writes.)  You still haven't answered whether you have any consistency requirements for reads while increments are happening.  If you just need the final count correct, you can chain separate .fetch_add(1, relaxed) with the high-half increment being conditional. If you need consistent reads, require your 32-bit halves contiguous and use them as atomic<uint64_t>. e.g. union with a struct is UB but works in practice

The code should have a sequential consistency and all reads should return a values in a strictly ascending order.

You might be able to skip locking some of the time, like when the low half is far from wraparound, but the readers will need to sometimes retry or wait some of the time, and yeah you'll need either a separate sequence number or to reserve some bits of one half for that.  The best choice of strategy probably depends on whether writes are so frequent they'll often contend, and how frequent writes are vs. reads.  And on any worst-case realtime guarantee for how long a writer or reader can stall, and how bad it is if a reader ever sees a jump or descending count if a sequence number wraps around.

I believe you are right, that I need to use some bits of some half for the synchronization. However, the problem here is that I do not have "reader-writer", every thread is technically both reader and a writer, calling the GET function and both incrementing the value and returning it
